# transition between points in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am currently trying to generate a curved line, which consists of three points. I would like to generate an animation where you can see how the line is created, that is, point to point. With my current code I do not know why the transition does not work
[image]

```
    var curved = d3.svg.line()
        .x(function(d) { return d.x; })
        .y(function(d) { return d.y; })
        .interpolate("cardinal")
        .tension(0)
    var points = [{x: 70, y: 52.5}, {x: 250, y: 250}, {x: 70, y: 447.5}];

    d3.select("#g-1").append("path").attr("d", curved(points)).transition().duration(2000);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/41bo44tt/

Comment: Look at your code: are you transitioning the path to **what**?

Comment: Is the path you have the desired final state? if so what is the desired initial state?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I do not understand much of the subject, I just want to have an animation from the first point of the line ({x: 0, y: 5}) to the end point {x: 30, y: 5}

Comment: @AndrewReid  I do not understand much of the subject, I just want to have an animation from the first point of the line ({x: 0, y: 5}) to the end point {x: 30, y: 5}

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I need that, look the picture please..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In D3, a transition selection will transition from a state A to a state B. Right now, in your code, there is **nothing** after the `transition()` method.

That being said, what you want can be achieved using different approaches. The classic one is just using the path's length to set the `stroke-dasharray`, setting the initial `stroke-dashoffset` to the length of the path and then, in the transition, changing it to 0:

```
var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

path.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
    .transition()
    .duration(2000)
    .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

Here is a demo using your code:

```js
var curved = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .interpolate("cardinal")
  .tension(0)

var points = [{
  x: 70,
  y: 52.5
}, {
  x: 250,
  y: 250
}, {
  x: 70,
  y: 447.5
}];

var path = d3.select("#g-1").append("path").attr("d", curved(points));

var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

path.attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
  .transition()
  .duration(2000)
  .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<svg width="300" height="500">
  <g id="g-1"></g>
  <g id="g-2"></g>
</svg>
```

Comment: great! thank you. what does this line? var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();    I dont understand  what is .node()?

Comment: `path` is just a D3 selection. `path.node()` is the actual DOM element.